# Nextjs using multiple parameters per slug

Tags: next.js

```
    export async function getStaticPaths() {
    const posts = getPagesToRender();
    const postPaths = posts.map((post, i) => {
        return {
            params: { page: post[1].replace(".md", ""), pageId: post[0] }
        }
    })

    return {
        paths: postPaths,
        fallback: false
    }
}
```

File names are like this: `[1]page1.md`
I pass it to getStaticPaths as

```
page: post[1].replace(".md", ""), pageId: post[0]
```

So they are like **page: page1 pageId: 1**

But It does not work because nextjs only expects 1 parameter. So I can only send the page parameter as nextjs ignores the second. Solution is to use 2 url slugs like this : `[pageId]/[page]`
But I don't want to pollute the url if possible.

**Can you send 2 parameters from 1 slug?**

Answer (score 4):

No, you should be using `[...slug].js` instead of `[slug].js`. This makes the parameters an array instead!

Comment: I think [...slug] is intended to use with multiple slashes. Like: /1/hello-world. I could not make it send 2 parameters for one slug, I am going to revert and just do /id/page. Thanks for the answer though